# CSS Navigation - First anchor/button in list does not work when all others do?

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-sprites

I have created a horizontal navigation bar similar to many I have done before.  Inexplicably, the first link does not function properly but all others do.  When I roll over the link with the mouse, two things are different in the first button: the cursor does not change to a hand as with all other links/clickable items on the page and the rollover effect does not function.  EDIT: Here is a link to all relevant materials: http://finchsbrasserie.com/NewSite/

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="bt1"><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
        <li id="bt2"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li id="bt3"><a href="#">Farmer's Page</a></li>
        <li id="bt4"><a href="#">Hours and Location</a></li>
        <li id="bt5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="bt6"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:410px;
width:520px;
height:100px;
}
#nav ul li {
display:block;
float:left;
height:100px;
position:relative;
border-right:1px solid #d6df22;
}
#nav ul li a{
background-image:url('NavSprite.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin:8px;
position:relative;
top:60%;
}
#bt1 a{
width:44px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px 0px;
}
#bt2 a{
width:48px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -40px;
}
#bt3 a{
width:96px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -80px;
}
#bt4 a{
width:125px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -120px;
}
#bt5 a{
width:62px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -160px;
}
#bt6 a{
width:44px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -200px;
}
#bt1 a:hover{
width:44px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -20px;
}
#bt2 a:hover{
width:48px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -60px;
}
#bt3 a:hover{
width:96px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -100px;
}
#bt4 a:hover{
width:125px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -140px;
}
#bt5 a:hover{
width:62px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -180px;
}
#bt6 a:hover{
width:44px;
height:10px;
background-position:0px -220px;
}
```

Comment: can I have an absolute link to the sprite?

Comment: and maybe an example of how that menu should look

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Jake.  Usually, posters add a *fiddle* that provides a live example for others to work with.  Here is a fiddle of your code.  As you can see, there must be something missing here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ygDDT/

Comment: @sg3s - I'm am currently on the move and cannot access my development server.  The sprite currently only lives locally on my computer.  Will upload when I can.

Comment: @Jason - I believe the fiddle is not working properly because the actual text is set to not be displayed and there is not an absolute link to the sprite, which is the only thing that should display other than a right border to each li.

Comment: @sg3s here is an absolute link to the sprite: http://finchsbrasserie.com/NewSite/NavSprite.png  It is a transparent png with alternate white text for rollover between the green text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo is hovering over the menu, so you effectively can't use the first menu item even though it is visible. (the logo has a transparent background over the link)

This is an easy fix, add some `z-index` to the menu:

```
#nav{
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:410px;
    width:520px;
    height:120px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

That should fix it.

Good thing you posted the website because this had nothing to do with the menu tbh :p

Comment: Perfect!  I figured it was something simple I just wasn't seeing.  Thank you.

Comment: came some seconds first before you ;)

Comment: This is a 2 second debug using the element inspector in say chrome or firebug, just try selecting the item directly where the behaviour occurs :p

Answer (score 0):

Here, it's working just fine with Chrome and IE. Though I find the hovering area's a little too small sized.

The only thing I see is the sixth item dropping down to the second line, because the div is too narrow (, or the items being too wide).

Comment: Interesting.  I do not have a problem with the sixth item dropping down to the second line in any browser.  I will definitely add a little more space to ensure this isn't a problem.  I agree the hover area is too small, will pad it a bit.  First item just will not act properly in any browser on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

replace this style with your at line 38 in mainstyle.css file

```
#nav {
height: 100px;
left: 410px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 520px;
z-index: 9999;
```

}

setting z-index to higher than logo will solve the problem.